# Add a second hyphen on newline of automatically hyphenated words

Tags: hyphenation

When automatically hyphenating, I would like to have a hyphen on the new line with the second fraction of the hyphenated word. Is there a straightforward way to make this happen automatically? Example below:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\section{Normal hyphenation}

Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. 

\section{Desired hyphenation} 

Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipisc{-}{-}ing semper elit. 

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: [A similar question about hyphenation.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332939/107497)  (But since it involves words that are already hyphenated, I don't think it's applicable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to *automatically* do this in pdfTeX, but if you are willing to use LuaTeX (compile with `lualatex` or use the LuaLaTeX menu option of your favorite editor), you can use `\prehyphenchar` and `\posthyphenchar`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\prehyphenchar=`\- % Which character to insert before the linebreak
\posthyphenchar=`\- % Which character to insert after the linebreak
\begin{document}

\section{Automatic hyphenation}

Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. 

\end{document}
```

[image]