# Optex: How to repeat hyphen on next line when hyphenating prehyphenated words automatically?

Tags: hyphenation, optex

In Czech, many words (e.g. compound adjectives like *modro-zelený*) contain a hyphen.
When these words are hyphenated, the hyphen is supposed to repeat on the next line to distinguish the meaning of similar words (*modro-zelený* and *modrozelený* look and sound similar, but they have different semantic meaning).
Words that contain a hyphen should be hyphenated like this:

```
This is an example modro-
-zelený text.
```

while words that don't should be normally:

```
This is an example modro-
zelený text.
```

In Latex, one can achieve this behaviour using Babel as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529453/268200) or it can be done using the `\discretionary` command as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332943/268200).
I was able to recreate the second solution in Optex:

```
\cslang
\fontfam[LMfonts]
\def\rephyph #1{\discretionary{#1}{#1}{#1}}

modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený modro\rephyph-zelený 

modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený modro-zelený 

\bye
```

[image: The code above typeset: Two paragraphs of the word "modro-zelený" repeating. In the first paragraph, the word is correctly hyphenated, i.e. the hyphen is repeated on the next line. The second paragraph shows the default behaviour.]

While it works correctly, it is quite burdensome to enwrap every hyphen in a command.
My question is: Is there a way to repeat the hyphen on the next line as described automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
\postexhyphenchar=`\-
```

at the beginning of your document but after setting the language.

Comment: Compared to other "solutions" cited above, this one is a relief. Thank you.

Comment: I’m not sure if OpTeX is different, but be aware you can find some surprising results with this solution. For example, `word---word` may add a hyphen after the em dash. But, well, just don’t use TeX ligatures.